# How do Eldar communicate without line of sight

Tags: warhammer-40k

According to the Eldar Lexicon entry, the language depends highly on non-verbal communication:

> This is largely because, as noted above, the Aeldari language is not actually comprised of words alone like human languages, but also accompanied by a detailed set of poses and gestures. The way an Aeldari stands, the cast of his features or how he moves his hands can all change the meaning of words, sometimes dramatically.

From [here](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Eldar_Lexicon).

So, how do Eldar communicate when they're not able to see each other or even with the helmet on? IMHO, they should not be able to just switch this sort of communication of as it's an essential part of their language. Has it been explained how this is done?

Comment: Just because the language includes those things doesn't mean it's not possible to communicate without them.  Consider that intonation is a normal part of speech, even in English, and yet deaf people can communicate in sign language without it.

Comment: Consider also special purpose languages like [Aviation English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_English) which is completely adequate for its purpose, but of minimal use outside it.

Comment: Out of all the fluff I've read, I've never heard of this... and I've read a big old bunch conversations and interactions between different Eldar. It's probably too tricky to write dialog taking this non-verbal system into account. So I'm going to assume even though it's in the Lexicon , it's largely ignored.

Comment: @DavidW sign language(s) are completely different to English, and use a range of features at least as diverse, if not greater, than most spoken languages.

Comment: @OrangeDog That completely misses the point.  In most languages, English _less so than most_, intonation carries information.  But that sign language works, irrespective of whether or not it is "English," demonstrates that intonation is not required.

Comment: @DavidW but how is that relevant to the question?

Comment: @OrangeDog If the premise in the second last sentence is incorrect, then the following question is effectively moot, no?

Comment: @DavidW: Aviation English is just a subset of English, with limited (specialized) vocabulary, with some variations since pilots have learned from incidents to avoid formulations that could be ambiguous or could be misunderstood when communication conditions are not optimal. I read once that actually 75% of communication between pilots, or pilots and air control, is dedicated to make sure that the meaning information (the remaining 25%) has been well understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Human *language* might be comprised of words alone ([although even that is not entirely true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silbo_Gomero)) but inter-human *communication* is also be based on [non-verbal signs, facial expressions, gestures etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonverbal_communication) as well as spoken words.

So the idea that this could be different for Eldar is a false premise, except that it might be more accentuated than for humans.  Eldar will communicate without line of sight the same way humans do, verbally or textually, but in person there will be an extra level of nuance and meaning added by their expressions and gestures, the same as with humans.